# Unexpected behaviour of macros in C

Tags: c, macros

How can both the following codes execute (The codes are same except the semicolon in second line)

This code is expected to execute and does so as well.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SWAP(a, b) int t; t=a, a=b, b=t  //note here is no semi-colon at the end
int main()
{
    int a=10, b=12;
    SWAP(a, b);
    printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

But the following is not expected to run as `SWAP(a, b)` will be replaced by `int t; t=a, a=b, b=t;;`.So two semi-colons should produce error!!!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SWAP(a, b) int t; t=a, a=b, b=t;  //note the semi-colon here
int main()
{
    int a=10, b=12;
    SWAP(a, b);
    printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: where do you get the idea that two semicolons should produce an error?

Comment: Why should “two semi-colons should produce [an] error”?  Have you tried a simple test to see whether the compiler accepts `;;` (without using your macro)?  Does it produce any errors or warnings?

Comment: "two semi-colons should produce error!!!" - why?

Comment: @H2CO3; Few days ago I saw a similar post in which `;;` caused a big problem. But I don't remember which post was that

Comment: that said, I'd change your macro to `#define SWAP(a, b) {int t; t=a, a=b, b=t;}` (with brackets), otherwise you'd get an error with `t` being defined more than once if you were to use the macro more than once in the same scope.

Comment: @filipe I would just make that a function anyway.

Comment: @haccks Quite reasonable. "big problem" is not the same as a "compiler error", though.

Comment: @H2CO3; Sorry! Let me dig that out.

Comment: @filipe: This version will not work well under `if`. For example, `if (1) SWAP(a, b); else;` will not compile. This is why we use `do{}while(0)` idiom for macros, instead of just a pair of `{}`.

Comment: I recall seeing some rather appalling code in a 1.1.x version of the Sun JVM where there were macros that generated the trailing `;`, and hence you'd code the statement `x = POP_Y` or whatever, without the trailing `;`.  (But even worse were macros that generated something like `if (x ==`.)

Comment: @AndreyT good point, forgot about the do while(0)... but like H2CO3 said, I would rather just make it a function instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The stray semi-colon becomes a null statement which is perfectly legitimate in C.

You could prove this by adding a line with a dozen semi-colons to your code.

Separately, your macro would be better written as:

```
#define SWAP(a, b) do { int t = a; a = b; b = t; } while (0)
```

This works better if you try to do two different swaps in a single block of code.

Comment: Few days ago I saw a similar post in which `;;` caused a big problem. But I don't remember which post was that.

Comment: Intriguing — can you dig that out?

Comment: Yes. At that time I run that code. I am searching for that post.

Comment: My bad! Didn't find that. But AFAIR, that macro was about loop.

Answer (score 4):

Extra semicolons in local scope will never produce an error in C (after C99) if used as in your macro. They simply introduce an empty statement. Where did you get the idea that it should be an error? One can concoct an example that would trigger, say, an "orphaned else" error because of an extra semicolon, but your macro is not usable under `if` anyway (see below).

In C89/90 it was possible to trigger an error through an inadvertently placed extra semicolon after a declaration, because in C89/90 it was illegal to mix declarations and statements. For example

```
int a, b;;  /* <- A declaration followed by an empty statement */
int c;      /* <- ERROR: Illegal declaration after a statement */
```

But in C99 it is not a problem, since declarations and statements can be mixed. Your `SWAP` is obviously implemented for C99 so this issue does not immediately apply though.

It is worth noting that such implementation of `SWAP` is pretty poor and quite dangerous. It might lead to unexpected, dangerous and completely meaningless behavior in contexts like

```
if (/* whatever */)
  SWAP(a, b);
```

Better follow the `do/while(0)` idiom and do something like

```
#define SWAP(a, b) do { int t; t=a, a=b, b=t; } while (0)
```

Note - no semicolon at the end.

Comment: You can, of course, get burned on `if (X) macroA else macroB;`, if `macroA` generates a gratuitous `;` at the end.

Comment: @Hot Licks: Yes, but the OP's macro is implemented as a declaration followed by a statement. Such implementation is not usable undef `if` (as in your example) for reasons that have nothing to do with the trailing `;`. It won't work (will lead to "orphaned else") in this context regardless of whether there is a trailing `;` in the macro or not.

Comment: The original macro, used with an `if` without braces, it tries to declare `t` as the body of the `if` but that isn't allowed.  Things go downhill from there.

Answer (score 2):

A semi colon on its own is an "empty statement," a statement that does nothing.

It is sometimes useful, but most of the time it's an error. For example this if-statement does not have the intended effect:

```
if (x == y);
{
    z=1;
}
```

Despite this fact, it's a perfectly valid part of the C language.

Answer (score 2):

After using

`gcc -E file_name.c` you'll get for second code :-

`int t; t=a, a=b, b=t;;`

which is a valid

and equivalent to

```
int t; t=a, a=b, b=t;

; // null statement does nothing
```